# Can we create lambda function using grunt instead of amazon console?

Tags: aws-lambda

I am creating a zip file for deployment to lambda using https://github.com/Tim-B/grunt-aws-lambda but when deploying to aws lambda I need to create the function first in amazon console. Can we create a function using grunt instead of amazon console? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the function from grunt using [AWS JavaScript SDK for Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html).

Use the [createFunction](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#createFunction-property) method as shown below.

```
/* This example creates a Lambda function. */

 var params = {
  Code: {
  }, 
  Description: "", 
  FunctionName: "MyFunction", 
  Handler: "souce_file.handler_name", // is of the form of the name of your source file and then name of your function handler
  MemorySize: 128, 
  Publish: true, 
  Role: "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/service-role/role-name", // replace with the actual arn of the execution role you created
  Runtime: "nodejs4.3", 
  Timeout: 15, 
  VpcConfig: {
  }
 };
 lambda.createFunction(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /*
   data = {
    CodeSha256: "", 
    CodeSize: 123, 
    Description: "", 
    FunctionArn: "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:function:MyFunction", 
    FunctionName: "MyFunction", 
    Handler: "source_file.handler_name", 
    LastModified: "2016-11-21T19:49:20.006+0000", 
    MemorySize: 128, 
    Role: "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/service-role/role-name", 
    Runtime: "nodejs4.3", 
    Timeout: 123, 
    Version: "1", 
    VpcConfig: {
    }
   }
   */
 });
```

Note: You can fill the code parameter with code or use addition attributes to refer a code zipped and uploaded to S3.

E.g.

```
Code: { /* required */
    S3Bucket: 'STRING_VALUE',
    S3Key: 'STRING_VALUE',
    S3ObjectVersion: 'STRING_VALUE',
    ZipFile: new Buffer('...') || 'STRING_VALUE'
  },
```

Also make sure to give required permission to the IAM User and [setup JavaScript SDK credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html) to run the code.